# Installing mongoose/mongodb via pre-configured webpack file - Excel JS API development

Tags: node.js, mongoose, webpack

I'm trying to start development of an add-in for Excel using the JS API. The Excel docs instruct you to use Yeoman to generate a node JS project which can then be tailored. I want to use MongoDB but when I try to require it and call mongoose.connect I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: mongoose.connect is not a function
    at ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js (taskpane.js:9:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:6:1
    at startup:7:1
```

Per the above, these are the two files referred to:

bootstrap (see throw e for source of error, near bottom):

```
// The module cache
var __webpack_module_cache__ = {};

// The require function
function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
    // Check if module is in cache
    var cachedModule = __webpack_module_cache__[moduleId];
    if (cachedModule !== undefined) {
        if (cachedModule.error !== undefined) throw cachedModule.error;
        return cachedModule.exports;
    }
    // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
    var module = __webpack_module_cache__[moduleId] = {
        // no module.id needed
        // no module.loaded needed
        exports: {}
    };

    // Execute the module function
    try {
        var execOptions = { id: moduleId, module: module, factory: __webpack_modules__[moduleId], require: __webpack_require__ };
        __webpack_require__.i.forEach(function(handler) { handler(execOptions); });
        module = execOptions.module;
        execOptions.factory.call(module.exports, module, module.exports, execOptions.require);
    } catch(e) {
        module.error = e;
        throw e;
    }

    // Return the exports of the module
    return module.exports;
}

// expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
__webpack_require__.m = __webpack_modules__;

// expose the module cache
__webpack_require__.c = __webpack_module_cache__;

// expose the module execution interceptor
__webpack_require__.i = [];
```

startup:

```
// module cache are used so entry inlining is disabled
// startup
// Load entry module and return exports
__webpack_require__("./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=wss%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=info&overlay=true&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true");
__webpack_require__("./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js");
__webpack_require__("./src/taskpane/taskpane.js");
var __webpack_exports__ = __webpack_require__("./src/taskpane/taskpane.html");
```

This is my code per the taskpane.js file which the yeoman generator provides (basically opens a small browser window embedded in Excel, hence "taskpane".

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/compston');

const mainNominalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  code: Number,
  name: String,
  category: String
});

const MainNominal = mongoose.model('Main Nominal', mainNominalSchema);

Office.onReady((info) => {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Excel) {
    document.getElementById("sideload-msg").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("app-body").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("run").onclick = run;
  }
});


export async function run() {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
      const ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
      const allNominals = await MainNominal.find({});

      await context.sync();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

I think there must be some step to configure webpack or the provided xml manifest to allow the use of additional third party modules, but I'm fairly new to this stuff so it feels like looking for a needle in a haystack.

This is the error that appears in the taskpane browser window:

```
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
Script error.
    at https://localhost:3000/taskpane.js:8287:58
```

Finally, I've copied the webpack.config below. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks very much.

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

const devCerts = require("office-addin-dev-certs");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');

const urlDev = "https://localhost:3000/";
const urlProd = "https://www.contoso.com/"; // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR PRODUCTION DEPLOYMENT LOCATION

async function getHttpsOptions() {
  const httpsOptions = await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions();
  return { ca: httpsOptions.ca, key: httpsOptions.key, cert: httpsOptions.cert };
}

module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      taskpane: ["./src/taskpane/taskpane.js", "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html"],
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.js",
    },
    output: {
      clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".html", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
          type: "asset/resource",
          generator: {
            filename: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "taskpane"],
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: "assets/*",
            to: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
          {
            from: "manifest*.xml",
            to: "[name]" + "[ext]",
            transform(content) {
              if (dev) {
                return content;
              } else {
                return content.toString().replace(new RegExp(urlDev, "g"), urlProd);
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "commands.html",
        template: "./src/commands/commands.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "commands"],
      }),
      new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ],
    devServer: {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      server: {
        type: "https",
        options: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
      },
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
    },
  };

  return config;
};
```